# Unknown error when trying to modify Image.Source in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, image, windows-8

I'm actually developing a Windows 8 C#/XAML app for the Windows Store. In this app, I want to show images depending on what the user selected just before. So, in the code behind, I try to modify the myImage.Source parameter. I do it like this :

```
myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/folder/imagename.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

This used to work in WPF applications for Windows 7, but there, in Windows 8, I got an error:

> System.Uri cannot be converted to Windows.Foundation.Uri. Consult http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=215849 to obtain details.

Of course, the link is useless, and I found nothing by searching the Internet. I'm kinda lost with this. So i'm here to ask for help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is `folder` folder located ?

Comment: That's the Assets folder, generated automatically when creating a new project. It is in the project folder.

Comment: Ok, I just found how to do it. Finally, the msdn helped me for something. I did like this : 

myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///folder/myImage.png"));

And this is working perfectly. Thanks to you two for helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Image.Source` property is of type `ImageSource`. Therefore, try the following example:

```
myImage.Source = "/YourApplicationName;component/folder/imagename.png";
```

Or this one:

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();
image.UriSource = new Uri(
    "pack://application:,,,/YourApplicationName;component/folder/imagename.png");
image.EndInit();
myImage.Source = image;
```

Comment: Not applicable to WinRT.